# TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bots, typeerror, innertext

I am working on styling of Bot using react. I need to match to a value that is passed in the card, not in the activity. This allows to identify the specific card(s) in the html document to be styled. I'm matching on the button text value:

```
  if ( action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY' ) {
                                console.log('message ');    
                                var x = document.querySelectorAll(".ac-container");
                                console.log('adaptiveCard length '+x.length);

                                let cards = Object.values(x);  
                                console.log('cards lenght ' + cards.length);
                                 for(let i = 0; i <= cards.length - 1; i++) {
                                            var inTxt=cards[i].children[2].innerText;//here facing error
                                            var res = inTxt.substring(0, 8);
                                            console.log('inTxt '+ inTxt +  ' i '+ i  + 'card lenght '+ cards[i].children[2].length);
                                               if(res==='Consumer')
                                                             {
                                                                    console.log('Consumer text '+ res);
                                                                   // cards[i].className += '.trigger';
                                                                }
                                        }

                            }
```

Any idea what could be issue.

Comment: Check if cards[i].children[2] is a valid html object.

Comment: The card probably doesn't have a 3rd child.

Comment: But inTxt  has values and I can see them in colsole.log.